# Adding metadata to individual fields in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a list of clinical documents which I plan to index with Solr. Individual statements within these documents can contain both positive and negative findings. So, while indexing these statements (sentences) as fields within a single document, I want to be able to add additional metadata to each field which determines whether the statement is positive or negative.
While querying, I want to exclude documents which contain negative findings.

Example:

```
/* Document1 */
The gallbladder is inflamed and thickened. The appendix is normal.

/* Document2 */
The gallbladder is not thickened. The appendix is normal

Querying for "thickened gallbladder" should return only the first document
```

One way to implement this is to index each statement as a separate document and have a separate field for positive/negative findings. Is that the best approach? Is there a way to store all the statements within the same document?

Comment: This requires natural language understanding. Depending on how structured your documents are, different approaches may need to be researched. You can also take a look at SolrUIMA at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA.

Comment: I am already using a NLP algorithm to determine if the statement is positive/negative. My query is regarding the best way to index these statements in Solr using the metadata (positive/negative) information

Comment: If positive/negative is per document, then add a string field with that value. Then you can index documents, instead of sentences.